# How to force Shotwell re-read metadata from images?

Tags: shotwell, metadata

I have some odd behavior of Shotwell: some of my ratings of a recent *event* photos have disappeared from the Shotwell's database.

Most of the photos that I had rated two stars are listed as not rated in Shotwell. However the file of the photo does say "rating 2", and Digikam as well confirms the rating is 2 when I reload the metadata from the photos.

Is there a way to **force Shotwell to re-read the metadata from the photos and overwrite what's in the database**?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Looks that there is no function for rebuilding database from photo files (in version 0.24.5 which I am using). The only way is probably delete the db file located `~/.local/share/shotwell/data/photo.db`. After restarting Shotwell you should make a new import.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would work for ratings, but I read a while that a trick to force thumbnail regeneration was selecting everything, mirror (or rotate, or whatever you want), and then undo the operation. That forces Shotwell to re-read the file, and might fix your problem.

It's pretty weird, though, because, I've even edited tags, rotation or whatever from external tools, and Shotwell has always managed to update its information.

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different issue but maybe it helps you too: I updated the CreateDate using exiftools but Shotwell would not recognize it.

It turned out that I had configured Shotwell to save all metadata to files. So every time I used exiftool Shotwell would just override my settings because it had stored something else in its database.

I switched of the option to save metadata in images and now it recognizes my changes made with exiftool.